# HTTP Error 500.19, error code 0x8007000d, while trying to use "URL Rewrite" in IIS 10

Tags: url-rewriting, samesite, applicationhost

I tried using `<rewrite>` in web.config and received **HTTP Error 500.19** error code 0x8007000d.

Went to IIS Manager, found the "URL Rewrite" icon (*which means that the module is already installed and I don't have to install it again*), but clicking on it gave a generic "There was an error while performing this operation" error.

It didn't matter which website (or the server itself) I selected, clicking on the corresponding "URL Rewrite" icon still gave the same error message.

At some point the error message started showing an additional detail: "*The configuration section 'system.webServer/rewrite/globalRules' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration*", I cannot recall changing anything, so I don't know what caused it to appear, so this is just an FYI.

I searched and found lots of other posts that contributed to the final solution, below are the steps that solved it for me:

Answer (score 1):

On your server:

Check if the **%SystemRoot%\system32\inetsrv\rewrite.dll** exists

If yes, open this config file in Admin mode: 
**%SystemRoot%\System32\inetsrv\Config\applicationHost.config**
(for 64 bit Windows make sure to use a 64 bit text editor, or you will get a 'file not found' error`) and check if you have the following 'rewrite' elements (Parent elements provided for structural reference only)

```
<sectionGroup name="system.webServer">
    <sectionGroup name="rewrite">
    <section name="rules" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
    <section name="globalRules" overrideModeDefault="Deny" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" />
    <section name="outboundRules" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
    <section name="providers" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
    <section name="rewriteMaps" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
    <section name="allowedServerVariables" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
</sectionGroup>



<globalModules>
    <add name="Rewrite" image="%SystemRoot%\System32\inetsrv\rewrite.dll" preCondition="bitness64" />



<location path="" overrideMode="Allow">
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <add name="Rewrite" preCondition="bitness64" />
```

In my case every  related part was missing in applicationHost.config, I had to add everything of the above. Saved the file, restarted IIS (may not be necessary but I had a luxury of doing it), clicked on the "URL Rewrite" icon again and the error was gone. After that I modified my website's web.config with the new  section and it worked as expected.